# Access SVG icons from javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, svg, icons

I have a javascript object with icons in SVG format

```
const icons = {
    // Icon for the "Add to cart" button
    add: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>`,
    // Icon for the "Remove from cart" button
    remove: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13H5v-2h14v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>`,
    // Icon for the "Remove all from cart" button
    removeAll: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13H5v-2h14v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>`,
    // Icon for the "Remove all from cart" button
};
```

I would like to use it in the HTML by

```
<span>{icons.add}</span>
<span>{icons.remove}</span>
```

Right now it is displayed as a string and icon is not rendered.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 2022, create your own `<svg-icon>` Native Web Component to write Semantic HTML
supported in all modern browsers, and in all Frameworks

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-icon", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">` + 
        `<path d="` + {
          add: `M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z`,
          remove: `M19 13H5v-2h14v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z`,
          removeAll: `M19 13H5v-2h14v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z`,
        }[  this.getAttribute("is")  ] + 
        `" fill="none"/></svg>`;
    }
  });
</script>

<svg-icon is="add"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="remove"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="removeAll"></svg-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`select`](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-the-different-ways-to-select-dom-elements-in-javascript) the element you need to insert the `svg` inside and use `innerHTML` to inject the `SVG` inside.

```js
const icons = {
    // Icon for the "Add to cart" button
    add: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>`,
    // Icon for the "Remove from cart" button
    remove: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13H5v-2h14v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>`,
    // Icon for the "Remove all from cart" button
    removeAll: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13H5v-2h14v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>`,
    // Icon for the "Remove all from cart" button
};

const addIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.add');
const removeIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');

addIcons.forEach(span => span.innerHTML = icons.add)
removeIcons.forEach(span => span.innerHTML = icons.remove)
```

```html
<span class="add"></span>
<span class="remove"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick. I was using SvelteKit and it has a method {@html} for this making it easier.

Comment: @jeff, you are welcome, I suggest to you to add `Svelte` keyword in the question to have the best answer related to `Svelte` syntax because without it everybody will think you need a solution with native `JS`

Answer (score 1):

I was using svelte. It has @html tag. I could simply use {@html icons.add}